# What's the best magento plugin to add support for affiliates?

Tags: magento, affiliate

I'm using magento 1.5 and prefer to install modules from Magento Connect. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am currently developping an affiliate extension for magento, I'm hoping to have it ready in the next few weeks. I'll need some beta tester...
If you'd like to give it a try, I'll be happy to install it for you (free of charge, of course) and to get your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you click Settings tab of your connect manager you will see “Preferred State” option there. If you’re installing extension with different “stability” or you get something similar to

   “Failed to download magento-community/xyz within preferred state “stable”, latest release is version 0.1, stability beta .. ”

   you should change this option to appropriate one. You should of course be careful with alphas and betas and know what you’re doing.

   If you are developer or just interested, ftp to downloader/pearlib/download after you install extension and you’ll find packed downloaded extensions there.
2. Magento upgrade

   You can also automatically upgrade your Magento installation through connect manager with key

   magento-core/Mage_All_Latest
3. Be sure all files are well unzipped in the directory downloader some of them were missing in my case

Comment: My question is about a specific kind of extension - affiliates programs. But thanks anyways.